# How to detect img in jQuery inside undefined parent?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to get to detect an image when alt + click on an img.

```
$("*").click(function(event){
    if(event.altKey)
    {
          var img = $(this).find("img");
          len = img.length;
          if( len > 0 ){
             alert($(img).attr('src'));
          }
        return false;
    }
});
```

This code is only working when you have one parent.

```
<body>
  <div id="div1">
     <div id="div2">
       <ol>
         <li>
           <a>      
             <img src="thesrciwannaget.jpg" />
           </a>
         </li>
       </ol>
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

In a case like this, it doesn't work. I'm working on a chrome extension and I want to do the equivalent of right click -> copy image URL but when alt + left click.

Thanks for you help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? I think you should check if you click on an image.

```
$("*").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    if(event.altKey)
    {
        if($(this).is("img"))
        {
            alert($(this).attr("src"));
        }
        else
        {
            var img = $(this).find("img");
            if(img.length)
            {
                alert($(img).attr('src'));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks ! It work well in most cases. Unfortunately, when the image is append in ajax just like google images it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
$("img").click(function(event){ ...
```

Means alot less overhead and should work regardless of parenthood.